# No graphical login after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, recovery-mode

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and the update window appeared. I did update and then when my PC restarted I had and still have this screen.

[image]

I know if I open grub and enter recovery mode:

[image]

I could reset the root password, but when I enter recovery mode it loads all files but when it finishes, the expected screen with options doesn't appear and I get a screen like the first one.

I have more than one recovery mode, but it's always the same, I get the login screen again.

What should I do?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I don't think it's correct. It is booting, but to a TTY and not a GUI.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Multiple of the links in [this answer](/a/162078/175814) address this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

A. Boot your PC with the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

B. Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

C. Use fdisk utility to list the partitions on a hard drive.

```
    sudo fdisk -l
```

Suppose it informs that `/` is `/dev/sda1`, continue running:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

In the open file paste these lines:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> Save File

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> Close nano

Continue running:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
exit
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked perfectly, and it works so much better now!!

Comment: Congratulations. I am glad that a proper procedure for your problem has resulted.